# Sqoop to dynamically create hive partitioned table from oracle and import data

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

I have a table in oracle (table name is TRCUS) with customer's details, partitioned based on year & month.
Partitions name in Oracle:
PERIOD_JAN_13,
PERIOD_FEB_13,
PERIOD_JAN_14,
PERIOD_FEB_14 etc

Now I want to import this table's data into HIVE using SQOOP directly.

Sqoop job should create a hive table, dynamically create partitions based on the oracle table partition and then import data into hive; into the respective partitions.

How can this be achievable using SQOOP ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it cannot be achieved using Sqoop. However, there is one method which I guess you might not know.

1. Create a table in Hive without any partitions.
2. Set dynamic partition modes

   `SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true;
    SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;`
3. Import data into Hive table that is not partitioned using Sqoop

   `sqoop import --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/database1" --username root --password cloudera --query 'SELECT DISTINCT id, count  from test WHERE $CONDITIONS' --target-dir /user/hive/warehouse/ --hive-table pd_withoutpartition --hive-database database1 --hive-import --hive-overwrite  -m 1 --direct`
4. Create another table with partitions
5. Overwrite into partition table from previous table

   `INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE pd_partition partition(name) SELECT id, count, name from pd_withoutpartition;`

Note: Make sure that column with which you want to partition is mentioned last during overwrite in select statement.

Hive Version : Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.13.1

Comment: Any improvement has come in sqoop to implement dynamic partition?